# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException | JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

i want to get the Number of Entries in a table in My java Project.

This is my code:

```
int count = 0;
Statement st = Mysql.con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs= st.executeQuery("select count(*) from keys where spieler =" +p.getName());
while (rs.next()){
    count = rs.getInt(1);
}
```

I am getting following `SQLEXCEPTION`:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your
SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the 
right syntax to use near 'keys where spieler =Pit910' at line 1
```

What is worng?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the `spieler` a text field in the DB?

Comment: You should never use manually concatenated queries, always go for a PreparedStatement, otherwise you are vulnerable to SQL Injeqtion. see http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: @Reimeus Yes it is a text field!

Answer (score 2):

`keys` is a [reserved MySQL keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) which needs to be escaped (either that or ALTER the table to give it a different name). Try this

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = 
    con.prepareStatement("select count(*) from `keys` where spieler = ?");
preparedStatement.setString(1, p.getName());
ResultSet rs= preparedStatement.executeQuery();
...
```

Comment: Thanks that works for me. I have a Insert Command with the Same error: Mysql.Update("INSERT INTO keys (spieler,key) VALUES ('" + p.getName() + "', '" + key + "')");

Comment: same applys there - `con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO ``keys`` (spieler, key) VALUES (?, ?)")` - some formatting issues should be single backticks around `keys` –  Reimeus 6 mins ago

Answer (score 1):

Use quotes around text field values,
You can optionally use backtick around field name or use table_name.field_name

```
ResultSet rs= st.executeQuery("select count(*) from 
              `keys` where spieler = '" + p.getName() + "' ");
```

Comment: Now i get this Error: 
[13:13:42 INFO]: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'keys where spieler = ' Pit910 '' at line 1